# Obfuscating sensitive data keeping data-properties intact

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, dataset

I am preparing a dataset for my academic interests. The original dataset contains sensitive information from transactions, like `Credit card no`, `Customer email`, `client ip`, `origin country`, etc. I have to obfuscate this sensitive information, before they leave my origin data-source and store them for my analysis algorithms. Some of the fields in data can be categorical and would not be difficult to obfuscate. Problem lies with the non-categorical data fields, how best should I obfuscate them to leave underlying statistical characteristics of my data intact but make it impossible (at least mathematically hard) to revert back to original data.

**EDIT:** I am attempting to apply a single transformation to the entire original data (if possible). As an example like a hash function but the hash would destroy underlying statistical properties of data, are there other methods ?

**EDIT 2:** To explain my scenario, as a followup from the comments from @Tim. I have data fields like:

```
'CustomerEmail', 'OriginCountry', 'PaymentCurrency', 'CustomerContactEmail',
'CustomerIp', 'AccountHolderName', 'PaymentAmount', 'Network',
'AccountHolderName', 'CustomerAccountNumber', 'AccountExpiryMonth',
'AccountExpiryYear', 'CustomerAccountNumber'
```

I have to obfuscate the data present in each of these fields (data samples). I plan to treat these fields as features (with the obfuscated data) and train my models against a binary class label (which I have for my training and test samples).

Comment: It seems you want to obfuscate every property individually. If this is part of  an attempt to anonymize your data you must be aware that it will not suffice, as such schemes hardly reduce identifability of customers.

Comment: Could you be more precise on characteristics of your data? E.g. I imagine that form credit card no you can learn about the bank that issued it, but is there anything else (if no than it is simply about giving random ID's to the banks etc.)?

Comment: @Tim thanks for your helpful hint. The data fields would later be used to build a pattern for predicting risk of a transaction. So I would have a certain pattern of `credit card no`, `customer email` combination that my algorithms would predict as a risky transaction. As a requirement of the data providing organisation, I would not be able to port the original data without masking/hashing/obfuscating it. I wanted to know the way this can be achieved so later I can analyse the data without having a scope to revert to original data.

Comment: It sounds like you would like to obfuscate your data but at the same time be able to identify certain users using your algorithm - it sounds like those two things are mutually exclusive. Isn't it..? Also now it sounds more like information security rather than statistical issue.

Comment: @Tim thanks for you patience and answering me. The problem is two fold, first the information security issue, while preparing my dataset. The second is about how best I can keep my data to be fit for analysis after my Information security step. My aim would not be to identify users but just to predict a risk of a transaction.

Comment: I understand, but still - is it that you want to identify a risk of a *certain* transaction rather then build a general model..? I.e. you want to predict a risk of a certain transaction, or find the general risk rules "transactions by males over 40 y.o. from country X are risky"? If it is about general rules than you don't need any individual features (e-mail, credit card number) but you have to extract some important features of them (e-mail domain, bank that issued a card, country that ip address originates from etc.)

Comment: @Tim Apologies for not making myself clear. I am not looking forward to find general risk rules, I am more focussed on building a general model.

Comment: Than I am confused and it is not clear for me what kind of features you need to keep and what you want to obfuscate... If you expanded description of your problem and provided an example it would be much easier to follow your problem.

Comment: @Tim Noted. Would provide a more detailed explanation soon when I have hands on data again. probably few hours from now.

Comment: I guess it depends what you're trying to do. Read this  and weep. http://newsoffice.mit.edu/2015/identify-from-credit-card-metadata-0129

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks for the insightful Link! My research interests at the moment are more simple. I just need to predict Risk/Non-Risk transactions.

Comment: My intent was to show that you have to be careful in obfuscation of sensitive data, since it may be statistically reconstructible to fairly high probability even after supposedly being obfuscated.